# Have image size to the window, but not the window to the image

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I've been working on how to do layouts and I've come across something that is bugging the heck out of me. Now, if I use the code below, the window takes up the entirety of my screen.

```
<Window x:Class="HDD_Drill_View.Windows.WndwMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="HDDC"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Name="wndwMain"
        Closing="WindowClosing"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowState="Normal"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Width="Auto"
                   LastChildFill="False"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <DockPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Resources\background.png"
                            Stretch="UniformToFill"
                            TileMode="None" />
            </DockPanel.Background>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                        Height="Auto"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Name="bttnGenerateReports"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Click="BttnGenerateReportsClick"
                        Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Generate" /><LineBreak /><Run Text=" Reports" /></TextBlock>
                </Button>

                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Name="bttnSurveyReport"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    UseLayoutRounding="False"
                    Click="BttnSurveyReportClick"
                    Margin="10">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Survey" /><LineBreak /><Run Text="Report" /></TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Name="bttnTimeChart"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    UseLayoutRounding="False"
                    Click="BttnTimeChartClick"
                    Margin="10">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text=" Time" /><LineBreak /><Run Text=" Chart" /></TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Name="bttnMaterialAcquisition"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    UseLayoutRounding="False"
                    Click="BttnMaterialAcquisitionClick"
                    Margin="10">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="  Material" /><LineBreak /><Run Text="Acquistion" /></TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                    Height="Auto"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--MaxWidth="800"
                    MaxHeight="80"--> 
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Resources\drildata2.jpg" />
            </StackPanel.Background>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Yet, if I uncomment the `Max Height` and `Max Width` in the last `StackPanel`, then it seems fine. Basically, I'm wanting my background image to NOT affect my window size. Is this possible? I'm trying to set the background of a `StackPanel` to an image.

Comment: Why dont you just set the window background as the image?

Comment: @MarkHomer: Because in this particular instance, I want it to be set into the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` from the Window.

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the problem. I still have to have the `Max Height` and `Max Width` set. But it does make it to where the `Window` is now only half my screen.